# Multiple bar chart segments in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm currently looking at this bar chart example.

http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/3HL4a/13/

In my own version I've been using a json array as the data and is structured like so.

```
[{"irish":"154187","non_irish":"309638","area":"Connacht"},
 {"irish":"588725","non_irish":"2182932","area":"Ireland"},
 {"irish":"180755","non_irish":"1017491","area":"Leinster"},
 {"irish":"189395","non_irish":"672660","area":"Munster"},
 {"irish":"64388","non_irish":"183143","area":"Ulster"}]
```

My question is how would I apply both data.irish and data.non_irish to the "y" attribute and generate bars for both as currently I can't work out how to apply both because the "y" attribute will only take one in its parameter.

```
var bar = svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "bar");

var bartwo =bar.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .style("fill", function(d,i) {
     return colours[i];
     })

      .attr("x", function(d,i) { return x(data[i].area); })
      .attr("y", function(d,i) { return y(data[i].irish); })
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .attr("height", function(d,i) { return height - y(data[i].irish); })
```

Any help would be truely appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like grouped or stacked bar charts. If so, see this [all-in-one example from the master](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967).

Comment: I'm not sure if it is as I want the non irish data bars to be positioned beside the irish speaking ones.

Comment: Try [**`this`**](http://jsfiddle.net/5stce/14/).

Comment: I don't think stacked bar chart is what I'm after I just want the irish and the none irish data bars displayed alongside each other , is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

This dual bar-chart might help you: http://nvd3.org/examples/multiBarHorizontal.html. It emphasizes on the contrast of the two dimensions as well as comparison of multiple groups in one dimension (E.g the number of Irish speakers in different areas).